Using json_normalize with pandas
I'm using the following code in python to flatten the json structure below, however it doesn't work for all levels. I'm interested in the tags.tags column data specifically shown on the picture below
pd.json_normalize(data['conversations'])
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

Json structure:
[{'type': 'conversation.list',
  'pages': {'type': 'pages',
   'next': {'page': 3,
    'starting_after': 'WzE3MTU3ODIxOTc=='},
   'page': 2,
   'per_page': 1,
   'total_pages': 46969},
  'total_count': 46969,
  'conversations': [{'type': 'conversation',
    'id': '1384780',
    'created_at': 1715780970,
    'updated_at': 1715782197,
    'waiting_since': None,
    'snoozed_until': None,
    'source': {'type': 'conversation',
     'id': '2197597651',
     'delivered_as': 'customer_initiated',
     'subject': '',
     'body': '<p>Outros</p>',
     'author': {'type': 'user',
      'id': '64ac5cacccd2b047',
      'name': 'Claudiney Pinho',
      'email': 'irmao.ir@hotmail.com'},
     'attachments': [],
     'url': None,
     'redacted': False},
    'contacts': {'type': 'contact.list',
     'contacts': [{'type': 'contact',
       'id': '64accccd71982047',
       'external_id': 'b363-cc8f--fb270b5e72e8'}]},
    'first_contact_reply': {'created_at': 1715780970,
     'type': 'conversation',
     'url': None},
    'admin_assignee_id': 5614527,
    'team_assignee_id': 5045796,
    'open': False,
    'state': 'closed',
    'read': True,
    'tags': {'type': 'tag.list',
     'tags': [{'type': 'tag',
       'id': '5379642',
       'name': '[BOT] Other',
       'applied_at': 1715781024,
       'applied_by': {'type': 'admin', 'id': '4685750'}},
      {'type': 'tag',
       'id': '5379660',
       'name': '[BOT] Connected Agent',
       'applied_at': 1715781025,
       'applied_by': {'type': 'admin', 'id': '4685750'}},
      {'type': 'tag',
       'id': '5379654',
       'name': '[BOT] Not Resolved',
       'applied_at': 1715781027,
       'applied_by': {'type': 'admin', 'id': '4685750'}},
      {'type': 'tag',
       'id': '7046337',
       'name': '[BOT] Portuguese',
       'applied_at': 1715781029,
       'applied_by': {'type': 'admin', 'id': '4685750'}}]},
    'priority': 'not_priority',
    'sla_applied': None,
    'statistics': {'type': 'conversation_statistics',
     'time_to_assignment': 0,
     'time_to_admin_reply': 189,
     'time_to_first_close': 1158,
     'time_to_last_close': 1228,
     'median_time_to_reply': 139,
     'first_contact_reply_at': 1715780970,
     'first_assignment_at': 1715780970,
     'first_admin_reply_at': 1715781159,
     'first_close_at': 1715782128,
     'last_assignment_at': 1715781159,
     'last_assignment_admin_reply_at': 1715781159,
     'last_contact_reply_at': 1715782179,
     'last_admin_reply_at': 1715782125,
     'last_close_at': 1715782198,
     'last_closed_by_id': 5614527,
     'count_reopens': 1,
     'count_assignments': 3,
     'count_conversation_parts': 28},
    'conversation_rating': None,
    'teammates': {'type': 'admin.list',
     'admins': [{'type': 'admin', 'id': '5614527'}]},
    'title': None,
    'custom_attributes': {'Language': 'Portuguese',
     'Conversation status': 'Open',
     'From': 'iOS / Android'},
    'topics': {'type': 'topic.list', 'topics': [], 'total_count': 0},
    'ticket': None,
    'linked_objects': {'type': 'list',
     'data': [],
     'total_count': 0,
     'has_more': False}}]}]

how the dataset is displayed
I wish to create a pandas data frame with flatten key:values in a table

Add a few sample rows of your expected data frame.

Your JSON data is invalid, has several unquoted strings like None, True, False. Check validity first, maybe it's just that.

@PepeNO This is JSON-compatible Python data, not JSON itself.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a site for specific questions, but there's no question here and the problem is a little vague. Please read [ask] and make a [mre] including desired output dataframe. See also How to make good reproducible pandas examples. If you could reduce the size of the input data, that'd be great.

Also, please don't post pictures of text. Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like code formatting (print(df)) or table formatting (print(df.to_markdown()).

You can try using pd.json_normalize function with the record_path and meta parameters.
This should flatten the JSON to different multiple levels of your choice, you can then further extract each nested lists or dictionaries into columns, which is of interest to you.
I have provided a code snippet for you, I am not using jupyter so you might need to test it but in theory this should work nicely, since the concept is true.
import pandas as pd

df = pd.json_normalize(
    data[0]["conversations"],
    record_path=["tags", "tags"],
    meta=[
        "id",
        "created_at",
        "updated_at",
        ["source", "id"],
        ["source", "author", "name"],
    ],
    meta_prefix="meta_",  # trying to avoid conflicts with available ids 
    errors="ignore",
)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

Also note you have many NaN which caused errors, also I had to use meta_prefix for id.
  applied_by.id  meta_id meta_created_at meta_updated_at meta_source.id  \
0       4685750  1384780      1715780970      1715782197            NaN   
1       4685750  1384780      1715780970      1715782197            NaN   
2       4685750  1384780      1715780970      1715782197            NaN   
3       4685750  1384780      1715780970      1715782197            NaN   

  meta_source.author.name  
0                     NaN  
1                     NaN  
2                     NaN  
3                     NaN  


D.lola, it works however I tried to loop over the indices and append the results to other variable. I came up with the error: "list indices must be integers or slices, not dict"
It works if I run 'all_data[0]["conversations"]' without 'i += 1'
    data_1 = []  # This will store the normalized data
    i=0
    
    for i in all_data:  # Iterating directly over items in all_data
        normalized_data = pd.json_normalize(
            all_data[i]["conversations"],
            record_path=["tags", "tags"],
            meta=[
                "id",
                "created_at",
                "updated_at",
                ["source", "id"],
                ["source", "author", "name"],
            ],
            meta_prefix="meta_",  # Avoiding conflicts with available ids 
            errors="ignore",
        )
        
        pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)
        
        # Append the normalized data to date_1
        data_1.append(normalized_data)
        
        i += 1
    
    # If you want to combine all DataFrames into one:
    if data_1:  # Check if date_1 is not empty
        final_data = pd.concat(data_1, ignore_index=True)


Hi Lucas, i becomes each element in all_data so it's a dict, not an index. does i contain each item you want in all_data? I am guessing you want to normalise i as well.  You can try replacing all_data[i] with just i let's see what happens and also no need for this i += 1 at the end. I hope it helps

It worked. Thank you
